# Boost.Asio - Make sure that other party received data

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio and sending a list to a client and closing the socket when finished. Somehow the client *sometimes* gets an End Of File error before he has received everything.

I'm guessing this has to do with the server closing the socket right after sending the last list entry. Is there an easy way to solve this async_send to call the handler only after the data has been successfully sent?

Or is my End Of File error coming from something else?

Comment: define "when finished". and show us some code.

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Asio is an operating system independent abstraction layer over TCP and UDP sockets. They provide no guarantee that the other application has received and processed the data. You will need to include this logic in your application, you may want to study the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

If you're closing the socket immediately after `async_send()` returns, this is incorrect. You should close it only after the completion handler is invoked.

Comment: What about closing it inside the completion handler? That's what I'm doing atm but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @jhasse closing the socket inside the completion handler is semantically the same as closing after it is invoked. You should post your code in the question if you'd like help.